# Как узнать что js скрипт подменяет картинки

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, веб-программирование, lazyloading

**Как узнать что за js-скрипт/-функция срабатывает во время подмены картинок тут - http://www.kuaikanmanhua.com/web/comic/9403/ ?**

Когда заходите на сайт, изначально загружается картинка wait.jpg:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А уже потом Js подменяет ее на другую.

Причем доступ к картинке напрямую заблокирован:
**Можно** http://p1.kkmh.com/image/160202/hjsbw1wva.webp-w750.jpg?sign=5865eb8ed45f28b3ba4d94c6ae1bb5ac&t=5b83b4f9
**Нельзя** http://p1.kkmh.com/image/160202/hjsbw1wva.webp-w750.jpg

То есть нужно еще передавать параметры, чтобы получить ее.

Изначально HTML картинки такой:

```
<img data-kksrc="http://p1.kkmh.com/image/160202/hjsbw1wva.webp-w750.jpg?sign=5865eb8ed45f28b3ba4d94c6ae1bb5ac&amp;t=5b83b4f9" class="kklazy " h="585" alt="第1话 天上掉下个帅哥哥" title="第1话 天上掉下个帅哥哥" src="https://static3w.kuaikanmanhua.com/static/img/wait2_c8b8029.jpg">
```

После меняется на этот:

```
<img data-kksrc="http://p1.kkmh.com/image/160202/hjsbw1wva.webp-w750.jpg?sign=5865eb8ed45f28b3ba4d94c6ae1bb5ac&amp;t=5b83b4f9" class="kklazy " h="585" alt="第1话 天上掉下个帅哥哥" title="第1话 天上掉下个帅哥哥" src="http://p1.kkmh.com/image/160202/hjsbw1wva.webp-w750.jpg?sign=5865eb8ed45f28b3ba4d94c6ae1bb5ac&amp;t=5b83b4f9" style="">
```

Все это делает JS.
Как я понял, тут основной JS код - https://static3w.kuaikanmanhua.com/static/js/pc/web_comic_9ff2725.js

Как найти этот "кусок"? Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: kkrsc ищите, не прогадаете. а еще есть сайты вроде http://jsbeautifier.org/ которые код делают читаемым

Comment: поставте бряк на изменение атрибутов у img

Comment: меняется [этой](https://pastebin.com/Cc1RLvnG) функцией. не знаю что вам это даёт.